# ffmpeg - how to overlay multiple rotated texts and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the command for ffmpeg in order to rotate one text and overlay it to my video, but how to do it if I have multiple texts to be rotated?

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex \
"color=black:100x100[c]; \
[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv]; \
[ct]setsar=1, \
drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha]; \
[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=30:ow=rotw(30):oh=roth(30):c=black@0[txta]; \
[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(30))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(30))+50':shortest=1" \
output_video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have three texts to be processed, then.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex \
"color=black:100x100[c]; \
[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv]; \
[ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
[t1]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 1':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text1][alpha1]; \
[text1][alpha1]alphamerge,rotate=30:ow=rotw(30):oh=roth(30):c=black@0[txta1]; \
[t2]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 2':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text2][alpha2]; \
[text2][alpha2]alphamerge,rotate=45:ow=rotw(45):oh=roth(45):c=black@0[txta2]; \
[t3]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 3':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text3][alpha3]; \
[text3][alpha3]alphamerge,rotate=60:ow=rotw(60):oh=roth(60):c=black@0[txta3]; \
[mv][txta1]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(30))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(30))+50':shortest=1[mv1]; \
[mv1][txta2]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(45))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(45))+50':shortest=1[mv2]; \
[mv2][txta3]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(60))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(60))+50':shortest=1" \
output_video.mp4
```

You may have to adjust the overlay co-ordinates to avoid overlaps.

Comment: How to place these overlays in different positions like center, topleft? @Gyan

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47725003/