# How i can add logo on any location on ffmpeg stream? This is my command :

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i "logo2.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,boxblur=2:1,scale=iw/1.75:-1,pad=iw+26:ih+26:13:13:color=blue [v1]; movie=bgmu.mp4:loop=999,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB) [v2]; [v2][v1]overlay=shortest=1:x=W-w-30:y=H-h-22 [v3]; [v3][1:v]overlay=0:0,setdar=16/9; [0:a]atempo=1.15, aecho=0.4:0.66:2:0.2, chorus=0.5:0.9:50|80:0.4|0.42:0.25|0.4:2|1.4, firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(100,0); entry(400, -4); entry(1000, -6); entry(2000, 0)',equalizer = f = 1000: width_type = q: width = 1: g = 2, equalizer = f = 100: width_type = q: width = 2: g = 5,pan=stereo|c0

Comment: Perhaps a bit of explanation will help.

Answer (score 0):

In `[v3][1:v]overlay=0:0`, the first `0` is x-coordinate measured from left edge of `[v3]` and 2nd `0` is y-coordinate measured from top of `[v3]`. So change those values. You can use `W`, `H`, `w` and `h` in your expressions, which are the width and height of `[v3]` and `[1:v]` respectively.

`[v3][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-10` means to overlay it horizontally center and vertically at the bottom leaving a margin of 10 pixels.

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=font='Roboto':text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(55*PI/180):ow=rotw(55*PI/180):oh=roth(55*PI/180):c=black@0[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(55*PI/180))+(W-w-(W*0.1))':y='min(0,W*sin(55*PI/180))+(H-h-(H*0.1))':shortest=1" output_video.mp4

Comment: I'm trying the above command to rotate as well as translate the text. But somehow I can not seem to get it right. Its not shown on the video

Comment: Fyi, I'll be placing it at different locations. The above command is trying to place the rotated text at bottom right of the video